# How to display Custom Page on Liferay startup

Tags: liferay

I am using Liferay 6 with Struts2 .
I am able to display my portlet and its working fine .

Now my question on liferay startup , (that is when i enter 
http:localhost:8086 ) it shows up default liferay screen 
(This screen ) 
[image]

Please tell me , how can we show our Custom JSP instead of this page .

Answer (score 1):

You can see that the page Welcome can be edited to achieve what you want customizing this page. The direct URL is **/web/guest**.